# Seashell occurrance

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life

Sometimes, sea shells accumulate on the sea shore, but sometimes they will instead be dragged back out to sea. What are the main physical factors that determine which of these things will happen?

Comment: Hi Brandon, welcome to Physics.SE!  It's very unclear what you're talking about, and what you're asking.  Can you give us some more information?

Comment: To expand on what zhermes said, this is a site for specific, answerable questions. If you're just looking to invite a discussion, this isn't the place to do it, as stated in our [FAQ#dontask].

Comment: Brandon, I've edited the question to make it follow the site's rules a bit better. Please feel free to undo this or re-edit the question if you don't like the new version.

Comment: With Nathaniel's edits this looks like an interesting question. Brandon, if you Google for "swash sorting" you'll get lots of relevant hits.

Comment: Thanks john...swash sorting is what I'm talking about. The beach near my house is full of shark teeth so predicting whether they will be on the beach or underwater is my focus.